# Getting object name from array

Tags: objective-c

There is an array of tiles

```
tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tile8,tileBlank, nil];
```

Is it possible to pull out an object in the array in the form of a string?  For example, tileArray[2] would return "tile3".

Edit:  Instead of attempting to return an object in the form of a string, I just need to check to see the number of correct places.  For example, I'd like to check to see how many of them match.  In this case, there would be 7 correct.

```
tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tile8,tileBlank, nil];

tileArrayCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tileBlank,tile8, nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instance variable names are mangled and removed by the compiler.  You can use a backing dictionary of instances to names like AutoLayout does quite easily with the `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` macro.

If you'd like the inverse-intersection of two arrays, you must first guarantee they contain the same objects, then you can call `-removeObjectsInArray:` on an NSMutableArray to get the objects that are unique to the target array.

For everything else, an NSMutableSet can be used along with `-unionSet` to get the count of all unique objects to each set.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I realize I may have asked the wrong question.  Is it possible to compare two arrays of objects and catch the differences of the two arrays?

Comment: Thanks.  Will this also account for if the objects are in different order?  The two NSMutableArrays will always have the same number of objects, but there will be an order difference.

Comment: @joshft91 What do you mean by "account for"? This method removes every object from the array it is called on which is in the array passed as its argument.

Comment: @joshft91 They must be in the same order to satisfy `isEqualToArray:`, but that's not what I'm talking about.  if array one has Obj1, and array two has ObjZ7, then the inverse-intersection won't remove Obj1 even if they are of the same class.  The arrays have to contain the same object, not necessarily in the same order, for removeObjectsInArray to work.

Comment: I updated my question to more clearly reflect what I am trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. An object cannot know the name of the variable that references it.  Especially since many variables might point to that object.

Instead, the object should have some extra code to return it's own name. Like say, by adding a `-(NSString*)name;` method.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I realize I may have asked the wrong question.  Is it possible to compare two arrays of objects and catch the differences of the two arrays?